# regex in Adaptive card is not working in MSTeams when posting via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-graph-teams

We are trying to add email regex validation in Adaptive cards in MSTeams.The following card is working expexted in Adaptive Card Schema Designer. It validates the input and for invalid email id format it shwos the error.

```
let card = {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Specify the type of text being requested:"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "myComment",
            "label": "style: text",          
            "errorMessage": "Please provide valid email-id",
            "regex": "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z0-9-]{2,4}$"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

When we post the same card to a MSteams channel using [sendmessage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) it renders the card correctly. But valid email-id also it throws the error message.

[image: MSTeams Adaptive card regex validation error]

The following request body is used :

```
let contentData = JSON.stringify(card);

{
                                        body: {
                                            contentType: 'html',
                                            content: `<attachment id=${cardAttachmentUUID}>`
                                        },
                                        attachments: [{
                                            id: cardAttachmentUUID,                                           
                                            contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
                                            content: contentData

                                        }]

                                    }
```

MSTeams API requires card body to in String. Hence we stringify the card using JSON.stringify(card)

Is that because of the JSON.Stringify() ? Without JSON.Stringify() MSTeams API throws invalid input format error .

Please help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please try it with the expression:-
 "regex": "^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$"

Comment: Hi @Sayali-MSFT , We tried the regex provided by you. It is not correctly validating for email-ids like raja@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com . It ssems MSTeams adaptive card implemention is not recognizing some regex char. Could you please provide the list of charactors or combination of charactors that the MSTeams reges validation is not supporting ? We will try to create a regex based on that.

Comment: have you getting same error as mention above "Please provide valid email id" after adding this mail id "raja@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"?

Comment: It is not showing error message for raja@mytenant.onmicrosof

Comment: We are able to repro that issue , We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: Hi @Sayali-MSFT, We are still facing this issue. Could you please check and update ?

Comment: Sorry for delay in response!!
We are actively checking the status of bug with engineering team and let you know the updates, if we have any.

Comment: Have you tested this with Graph API as well?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT We are using BOT Rest API to post the card using POST v3/conversation API